# Excel automation - disable SQL login dialog when refreshing queries

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I am using Excel automation to refresh the SQL queries (workbook connections) embedded in an Excel 2010 workbook and then output the spreadsheet to PDF at scheduled intervals.  Everything works fine, except when the SQL server is offline/unavailable which will happen from time to time.  I just want to ignore the problem and continue, but Excel seems to insist on displaying the 'SQL Server Login' dialog window which then halts my program until the dialog box is closed.  Is there any way of disabling this dialog?  I have tried the following :

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

This stopped the error dialog but doesn't prevent the 'SQL Server Login' dialog.

Comment: How does your code know when a connection is successful? If it is then  you want to continue if not then you want to find and click the the cancel/ok button possibly. It's quite easy with `FindWindow` or `FindWindowEx` api functions.

Comment: btw the Application alerts are the Excel's own dialog boxes not external programs which I think you're refering to

Comment: Hi, the .Refresh method for the query doesn't complete until the SQL login dialog has been closed so not sure where/how I could use FindWindow, unless somehow on another thread?  The .Refresh waits even if the 'BackgroundQuery' property is set to True.

Comment: For example there is a program called Windows Detective or Spy++ which allows you to find handles for windows. So what you would do is stop your macro if the login box pops up and start a different sub which would identify the window and send a message to it (like CLOSE msg)

Comment: Hi mehow, I was able to solve the problem by running the FindWindow command on a background thread while the .Refresh method runs on the main thread.  If the window is found then I use PostMessage(hwd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0) to close the dialog - works fine.  If you post your FindWindow solution as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I am glad you've solved it @Jonathan Wareham :) You can answer your own question and accept it. You can post the code you're using if you think it may help any future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using `FindWindow` (running on a background thread) to check for the appearance of the SQL login dialog, then using `PostMessage` to close the dialog allowing the program to continue unattended.  See code :

```
var
  blnTerminateThread: Boolean;

function CloseSQLLoginDialog(Parameter: Pointer): Integer;
var
  hwdSQLLoginDlg: THandle;
begin
  Result := 0;
  hwdSQLLoginDlg := 0;
  blnTerminateThread := False;
  while (hwdSQLLoginDlg = 0) and (blnTerminateThread = False) do
    hwdSQLLoginDlg := FindWindow(nil, 'SQL Server Login');
  if (hwdSQLLoginDlg <> 0) then
  begin
    // Close the 'SQL Server Login' dialog window
    PostMessage(hwdSQLLoginDlg, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
    Result := 1;
  end;
  EndThread(Result);
end;

...

XLBook.Connections[intCount].OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery := False;
intThreadID := BeginThread(nil, 0, Addr(CloseSQLLoginDialog), nil, 0, intIDParam);
blnRefreshResult := XLBook.Connections[intCount].OLEDBConnection.Refresh;
blnTerminateThread := True;
CloseHandle(intThreadID);
```